# Spark SEMI/ANTI JOIN as boolean test

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark SQL, is there a way you can do a SEMI JOIN or ANTI JOIN as a boolean test?

I often have the equivalent of

`case when [not] exists(select 1 from ... subquery) then 1 else 0 end`

SEMI and ANTI JOIN are not quite what I want - I don't want a `WHERE [NOT] EXISTS`, I want a `CASE WHEN EXISTS` in the `SELECT`.

The best I could do is something like

```
SELECT case when b.id is [not] null then 1 else 0 end as exists_flag
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id
```

But this isn't great for two reasons

- have to worry about duplicates - may need to 'distinct' or aggregate before join (didn't have to worry about duplicates for EXISTS)
- aliasing - ending up with multiple columns with same name in result set; can't do a natural join if I need to distinguish between a.id/b.id

Is there a better way to do this?